# MessageDigest ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, md5, indexoutofboundsexception

I use `MessageDigest` to calculate the md5 signature in my project, but during the performance test it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I have found a few posts that suggest this is because `MessageDigest` is a singleton and not thread safe. Does anyone know how I can get around this problem, or if there is an equivalent `MessageDigest` class that is thread safe?

Comment: We're gonna need to see some code to be able to help you.

Answer (score 21):

> somebody says that this is beacause `MessageDigest` is singleton

That would be *your* `MessageDigest` object. Not the class itself. `MessageDigest.getInstance()` always returns a new instance: see the Javadoc.

> and not thread save.

Thread *safe.*

> Now, anyone knows how to solve this problem

Don't share your MessageDigest instance among multiple threads. Don't even make it a class member, make it a local variable in the method(s) that call it.